# Escaping doublequotes in AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have Google Analytics enabled in the account and there is one link that get broken when the analytics code is appended to it. After talking to ET/SFMC Support they suggest concatenating the link. However, I have a style applied to it and the double quotes do not work. I tried escaping the characters or replacing the double quotes with single quotes and it still doesn't work. Do you have any suggestions?

Example:

```
%%=V(CONCAT("< a href=",@Confirmation_URL," style=\'color: rgb(57, 181, 73); text-decoration: none;\' target=\'_blank\'>",@Confirmation_URL,"</a>"))=%%
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need the `v()` function.  No need to escape the single quotes, you're just missing a single quote after the `href`:

```
%%=concat("<a href='", @Confirmation_URL, " style='color: rgb(57, 181, 73); text-decoration: none;' target='_blank'>",@Confirmation_URL,"</a>")=%%
```

Comment: Is there a way to escape double quotes?

Comment: Yes.  It's described in the `Constants` section on the [AMPScript Syntax Guide](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/) page.

Comment: another option is to pass the ascii value for doublequotes into the char() function.  Example:  %%=concat("<a href=",char(34),@confirmation_URL,char(34),">",@Confirmation_URL,"</a>")=%%